# Jquery dynamic on blur child element of x textareas / div with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is like this:

```
<div class="div1">
    <textarea class="area1"> </textarea>
</div>
<div class="div1">
    <textarea class="area1"> </textarea>
</div>
<div class="div1"> 
    <textarea class="area1"> </textarea>
</div>
```

All the `divs` are dynamically added and the structure with similar class for each `div` and `textarea` is predefined.

When trying to trigger an `onblur` event with jquery on `nth-child(x)`, I get the event triggered on all `textareas` using example below.

```
$(document).on('blur', '.area1', function() {console.log($(this).val());});
```

I tried the following to get the `nth-child(2)` or `nth-child(x)` but it is insufficient:

```
$(document).on('blur', '.area1', ':nth-child(2)', function(){console.log($(this).val());});
```

**How can I get only the 2 child or child x?**

Hope someone has a good solution! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on('blur', '.area1:eq(1)', function(){console.log($(this).val());});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your pseudoclass attached to the selector `.area1` with a colon because, though it is a pseudoclass, it is a part of the selector.

Comment: Aha, thanks :) it didnt work with :nth-child(2) tho, but with :eq(2) it worked, don't know why :nth-child(2) didn't work.. hm, but thanks for trying to help! :)

Comment: I made a silly error. It didn't work with :nth-child(2) because there is no child of the textarea with class "area1". It was referencing a nonexistent element. It would have worked with .div1:nth-of-type(2) > textarea.area1 but :eq does a better job since it finds all elements of class area1 in the document and stores them in an array. Which is why :eq(1) gives you the second .area1 element (arrays begin at 0).

Comment: Aha, thank you, learned a lot about child elements just now :) thanks again